# Vue.js - Interpolation error - how to rework style to v-bind:style?

Tags: javascript, css, interpolation, vue.js

I am currently getting this console error message:

> interpolation in "style" attribute will cause the attribute to be discarded in Internet Explorer. Use v-bind:style instead.

Which is caused by this piece of code:

```
    <div class="placeholder-img" 
    style="background-image: url({{ travel._source.field_image[0].url }})">
```

Now I don't know how to change this to proper syntax, it would not be hard if the background image didn't contain the url() part but now I am a bit confused on how to properly refactor this. Could anybody help me out?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="placeholder-img" 
    v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + travel._source.field_image[0].url ')' }">
```

When using shorthand for v-bind:

```
<div class="placeholder-img" 
    :style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + travel._source.field_image[0].url ')' }">
```

When using ES6 syntax:

```
<div class="placeholder-img" 
    :style="{ 'background-image': `url(${travel._source.field_image[0].url})` }">
```

Comment: @dwenzel @Yerko Palma I have something similar but I am getting an error in the console for my bound :style ```:style="{ 'background-image': `url(${invitedClass.imagePath})`}"></a>``` and the error is: ```[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: Unexpected token ':' in
```Why is it not liking the colon?

Comment: @PA-GW - can you post the entire tag?

Comment: @dwenzel - this is the full anchor tag: ```<a :href="route" target="" class="card-image"
         :style="{ 'background-image': `url(${invitedClass.imagePath})`}"></a>``` and this is is my vue component declaration ```<div id="app">
                            <classes :route="{{ route('classes.show',['id' => $invitedClass->id]) }}"></classes>
                        </div>```

Comment: @PA-GW - Not seeing anything obvious... I would ask a separate Stack Overflow question, as this looks different from the initial one